# How to remove the index out of bound error in my program?

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I have tried various ways of removing the index out of bound error by changing the upper limits of the array.But the error persists. Where am I going wrong?

[Screenshot of my excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk0eY.png)

My program reads values(all rows) in the first column of excel sheet and finds the maximum value. Then based on the maximum value,criteria are formulated and the values are classified as Low,Medium,High and written back into a new excel sheet.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WriteException;

public class Bus3{

List<String> numbusarray = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> numcommutersarray = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> numcommercialarray = new ArrayList<String>();
    static WritableWorkbook workbook;
        static WritableSheet wSheet;


public void readExcel() throws BiffException, IOException, WriteException//method to read       contents form excel
{
    String FilePath = "Bus1.xls";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max=0;

    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("Bus1");// TO get the access to the sheet
    int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();// To get the number of rows present in  sheet
    int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();// To get the number of columns present in sheet
    System.out.println(totalNoOfRows);
    //adding excel contents from every column to arraylist
    for (int row = 1; row <totalNoOfRows; row++)
    {
        numbusarray.add(sh.getCell(2, row).getContents());
    }


    for (int row = 1; row <totalNoOfRows; row++)
    {
        numcommutersarray.add(sh.getCell(3, row).getContents());
    }

    for (int row = 1; row <totalNoOfRows; row++)
    {
        numcommercialarray.add(sh.getCell(4, row).getContents());
    }
    //to find maximum of numbusarray
    max=Integer.parseInt(numbusarray.get(0));
    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows-1; row++)
    {   
               if(!(numbusarray.get(row)).isEmpty())
               {
               int intNumber=Integer.parseInt(numbusarray.get(row));
               if(intNumber>max)
               {
                max=intNumber;
                //System.out.println(max);
               }
               }


    }
    System.out.println(max);
    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("sampletestfile.xls"));
    WritableSheet wSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    int increment=max/3;
    int a=increment;
    int b=a+increment;
    int c=b+increment;
    for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows-1; row++)
    {   
               if(!(numbusarray.get(row)).isEmpty())
               {
               int compare=Integer.parseInt(numbusarray.get(row));
               if(compare<=a)
               {Label label= new Label(0, row, "Low");//column,row,strngdata
               wSheet.addCell(label);}
               else if((compare>a)&&(compare<=b))
               {Label label= new Label(0, row, "Medium");//column,row,strngdata
               wSheet.addCell(label);}
               else
               {Label label= new Label(0, row, "High");//column,row,strngdata
               wSheet.addCell(label);}
               }
    }              
 /*Iterator itr=numbusarray.iterator(); //to print arraylist demo 
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
        System.out.println(itr.next());  
    }*/
    }//end of method to read contents from excel   
    //to close file
    public static void closeFile()
    {
        try {
            // Closing the writable work book
            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();

            // Closing the original work book
        } catch (Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws BiffException, IOException, WriteException  //main class
    {
        Bus3 DT = new Bus3();
        DT.readExcel();
        Bus3.closeFile();
    }//end of main class

}
```

Comment: Debug it, otherwise post your stack-trace

Comment: start row with 0. Don't start from 1. All these for loops where you initialize i = 1, make them i = 0. Then try

Comment: `row < totalNoOfRows-1` will reduce the size by two. Check for this condition.

Comment: I have started most of my for loops from 1 because the entries i need to read from the excel sheet starts from the 1st row. @FarazDurrani

Comment: I have 15 rows (totalNoOfRows) in the excel sheet and i have to read from the first row. Therefore the for loops range from 1-14(14 terms). Then for the maximum function the for loop ranges from 1-13 as i have assigned the 1st term as "max" initially. Finally the last for loop ranges from 0-13(14 terms) @Maverick

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size:
0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.getSheet(WritableWorkbookImpl.jav
a:399)
        at Bus3.readExcel(Bus3.java:69)
        at Bus3.main(Bus3.java:115)
Error being displyed @Yohannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your sh Sheet.class object doesn't have cells with column = 4.
This should fix it:

```
    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        numbusarray.add(sh.getCell(1, row).getContents());
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        numcommutersarray.add(sh.getCell(2, row).getContents());
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        numcommercialarray.add(sh.getCell(3, row).getContents());
    }
```

**LAST EDIT:**

```
    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        numbusarray.add(sh.getCell(1, row).getContents());
    }

    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        numcommutersarray.add(sh.getCell(2, row).getContents());

    }

    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        numcommercialarray.add(sh.getCell(3, row).getContents());
    }
    // to find maximum of numbusarray
    max = 0;
    for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
        if (!(numbusarray.get(row - 1)).isEmpty()) {
            int intNumber = Integer.parseInt(numbusarray.get(row - 1));
            if (intNumber > max) {
                max = intNumber;
                System.out.println("max: " + max);
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(max);
    workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("sampletestfile.xls"));
    WritableSheet wSheet = workbook.createSheet("name", 0);
```

Comment: I have additional two rows ahead. The number of buses is my 3rd column so i think the index 2 i have given is right. @Rinat

Comment: Also should be changed: max = 0;
  for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
   if (!(numbusarray.get(row - 1)).isEmpty()) {
    int intNumber = Integer.parseInt(numbusarray.get(row - 1));

Comment: And this: workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("sampletestfile.xls"));
  WritableSheet wSheet = workbook.createSheet("name", 0);

Comment: It finally worked! Your second suggestion was the answer to the error.Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like a very complex problem. 
Index out of bounds means that you are trying to access a position in the array that does not exists.
Watch your `numbusarray` variable, probably `row` is being set to an invalid index.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size:
0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.getSheet(WritableWorkbookImpl.jav
a:399)
        at Bus3.readExcel(Bus3.java:69)
        at Bus3.main(Bus3.java:115)

Comment: The above is the error being displayed. numbusarray array contains 14 terms. So 0-13 is the limit i have given for numbusarray

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, for me what worked was to create a new xls file, and copy the data from the old to the new one. and the errors stopped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31304571)